# Show that $f(x + iy) = \sqrt{|x||y|}$ satisfies CR equations at (0, 0)

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $$f(x + iy) = \sqrt{|x||y|}$$

Show that this function satisfies the cauchy-reimann equations at $z = (0, 0)$ but is not differentiable there.

I tried to evaluate

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\sqrt{|y|}}{2\sqrt{|x||y|}} 
$$
I know that I'm playing fast and loose with absolute values here, but the problem is that even restricting this to $$(\mathbb R^+, \mathbb R^+)$$ causes the evaluation at 0 to not exist.

So, I was wondering how to

a. Evaluate $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ at $(0, 0)$ and

b. show that the derivative does not exist

Answer (score 4):

Hints:  To show the CR equations hold at $0,$ the formula is just a distraction. Just notice $f$ vanishes on both the $x$ and $y$ axes. For the second part, we do need the formula. If $f'(0)$ exists, then $f'(0) = 0$ (just by looking at the axes again). So then we would have $\lim_{t\to 0} f(t+it)/(t+it) = 0$ as well. Is that true?

Comment: Ahh, thank you for the help! :) However, how do I show that the derivative does not exist? (just because $f(z) = 0$ does not mean that the derivative cannot exist, right?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat I added to my answer.

Comment: (+1) As always, I enjoy reading your solutions and appeal to "So-Crates" method.  Party on Z-man.

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you MV! I noticed that the overlords of MSE cancelled our previous "greetings and salutations" exchange. They may cancel this one too.

Comment: It does seem a bit "George Owellian."  And one of the new moderators seems to have a special dislike for me and I have received coincidentally an onslaught of down votes for some to fhe 9 MSE questions I've posted over the years (and I believe that my questions have more than passed the MSE requirements) and some of the answers (some of which did respond to questions that were not of the "highest quality") that I've posted.